# 3D NumPy array to 2D and getting two different 2D array from a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D NumPy array (2700, 4000, 2) and I want to convert it two different 2D array. I mean, my new two arrays will be (2700,4000).

I am new at Python programming. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Assuming you meant to say 2 `(2700, 4000)` arrays. It might help if you explain *why* you'd prefer two 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here you go.

**Code**

```
#Define the 3D array
n1 = np.ones((2700,4000,2))
#Get the first 2D array
n2 = n1[:,:,0]
#Get the second 2D array
n3 = n1[:,:,1]
print("Original Shape : ", n1.shape)
print("First array shape : ", n2.shape)
print("Second array shape : ", n3.shape)
```

**Output**

```
Original Shape :  (2700, 4000, 2)
First array shape :  (2700, 4000)
Second array shape :  (2700, 4000)
```